# Problems with jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I have two buttons, one for subtracting and one for adding. I also have two labels, one in between the two buttons that says how many times you've clicked the button and the other one next to the add button which tells you the total. I created the basic functionality of this but I am now trying to create a function that can be re-used to add more of these buttons. I have 4 parameters which are name (Class of the button), max (Maximum allowed total), min (Opposite of maximum) and step (By which it increases). At the end I have a total which should display the value of the totals if I had more button/forms. I need this code to be reusable in order to add more as needed.

Here is my original code: (http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinBurciaga/0gfrntve/)

```
var sum = 0;
var clicks = 0;
$('input').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('add') && sum < 25) {
        sum += 5;
        clicks++;
    }
    if ($(this).hasClass('minus') && sum > -25) {
        sum -= 5;
        clicks--;
    }

    console.log(sum);

    $('label').html(sum);
    $('.clicks').html(clicks);
});
$('label').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {
    var total = sum + clicks;

    $('.total').html(total);
});
```

New code which doesn't work correctly (sum starts over from 0) (http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinBurciaga/uufs6xjm/)

```
var set = function (name, max, min, step) {

    $(name).click(function () {
        var sum = 0;
        var clicks = 0;

        if ($(this).hasClass('add') && sum < max) {
            sum += step;
            clicks++;
        }
        if ($(this).hasClass && sum > min) {
            sum -= step;
            clicks--;
        }

        console.log(sum);

        //$('label').html(sum);
        //$('.clicks').html(clicks);
    });
};
set('input', 25, -25, 5);



$('label').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {
    var total = sum + clicks;

    $('.total').html(total);
});
```

I'm a beginner at jQuery/JavaScript and I would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: `var sum = 0; var clicks = 0;` is always being set to zero on every click

Answer (score 0):

Every click you reset the numbers, move it to outside the click

```
//sum and clicks should be defined here
$(name).click(function () {
    var sum = 0; <---wrong
    var clicks = 0; <---wrong
```

and you mess up your copy and paste, of course it has a method hasClass which is truthy

```
if ($(this).hasClass && sum > min) {  <---wrong
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put declaration of the sum out side or you should save that in any input and get again from it.

**Either** put them outside :

[Fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/uufs6xjm/3/)

```
var sum = 0;
var clicks = 0;
set('input', 25, -25, 5);
```

**OR** get sum from the label again..

[Fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/uufs6xjm/4/)

```
var sum = parseInt($('label').html());
var clicks = parseInt($('.clicks').html());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var sum = 0; 
var clicks = 0;
var set = function (name, max, min, step) {    
    $(name).click(function () {


        if ( $(this).hasClass('add') ) 
        {
            if(sum < max){
                sum += step;
                clicks++;
            }
            else{
                //sum = 0;
            }
        }
        if ($(this).hasClass('minus')) {
            if( sum > min){
                sum -= step;
                clicks++;
            }
            else{
                //sum = 0;
            }            
        }

        console.log(sum);

        $('label').html(sum);
        $('.clicks').html(clicks);
    }); 
}; 
set('input', 25, -25, 5);



$('label').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {
    var total = sum + clicks;

    $('.total').html(total); 
});


//$(this).prop('disabled', false);
```

Comment: if you are new to jQuery/JavaScript then go for tutorial like this:
http://javascriptissexy.com/how-to-learn-javascript-properly/